# Rotating a 2-dimensional array n degrees in java

Tags: java, math, rotation

I'm making a 2d physics engine, when ever a object(like a chair) is spawned, it creates a 2d boolean array twice the size of the original image(to allow for rotation) and creates a shape the same as the image(excluding pixels of a oppacity less than 1)

how would I rotate this array x degrees?

rotate the true values in this x degrees, where "this" can be any shape
f=false t=true

```
f f f f f f f
f f f f f f f
f f T T T f f
f f T T T f f
f f T T T f f
f f f f f f f
f f f f f f f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic image rotation algorithm, except that you're just rotating a T/F bitmap, correct?

From my notes:

http://www.leptonica.com/rotation.html

http://datagenetics.com/blog/august32013/index.html

Rotation by shear:

Catmull & Smith

Very fast; implemented by rasterops.  Can be done in place.

Rows of pixels are moved a distance proportional to their vertical
  distance from the center of rotation.  A sequence of three alternating
  H,V,H shears perform the rotation.  For small angles (< 3 degrees),
  it can be done with two shears

Distortions can accumulate; if you were to rotate an image using
  180 rotations of 12 degrees each, the result would be effectively
  encrypted.  However, "unwinding" the image would restore it.

```
R = [  cos(a) sin(a) ]
    [ -sin(a) cos(a) ]


  = [ 1  tan(a/2) ] [    1     0 ] [ 1  tan(a/2) ]
    [ 0     1     ] [ -sin(a)  1 ] [ 0      1    ]
```

Note:  first rotate in steps of 90° so that a <= 45

---

I have C code for a similar algorithm that does arbitrary rotation, scaling, and translation of an image, all with integer math, but it's big and hairy and probably not appropriate for your problem.

Frankly though, I'd just look around and see if there's already an implementation in Java; look for 2-d graphics libraries.